# Multi Display configured to cube like format?

Tags: raspbian, hardware, display

I was wondering if there was any program or way for a pi/alternative SBC to output to several displays 4-6 as a single canvas. The wrinkle is that this single canvas needs to wrap around as if each display was a side of a cube like structure. Hopefully in as compact a solution with as few pis/SBC as possible.

I know this might become quite involved on the software or hardware level unfortunately. I just want to know if it is feasible and to be set on the right path.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using something like [this](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/2-way-hdmi-splitter-n08gf) it would be possible to split the 1 HDMI port on the Pi into 2. An alternative is to use [this](http://www.geek.com/chips/adding-a-second-display-to-your-raspberry-pi-just-got-much-easier-1604080/) board from Gert, which adds a second HDMI port using the GPIO pins.

However this is going to just duplicate them, to get the screens to extend is going to be much more difficult. As a side note, the more you split the signal the more desegregated it is going to get. So this is something to consider

Also be aware of the potential stress you could be putting on your Pi through connecting lots of displays to it.